# Slow CouchDB queries, is this normal?

Tags: couchdb

Even the simplest query on a 2-document database takes a minimum of 50ms to return a response on my localhost. 50ms seems abnormally slow for such basic index queries.

How long is a response normally expected to take? 50ms, 20ms, 10ms, 5ms, ...?

(CouchDB 1.6.1)

Comment: It depends. The real question is, is this a problem for your application?

Comment: If it wasn't a problem I wouldn't have posted this question. 50ms is a huge amount for an application where typical users consider anything over 100ms total noticeably slow.

Comment: And this is just on a localhost machine with a simple query on a tiny database, I can't imagine how this would scale live in a distributed production environment.

Comment: On my primary development system, both proxied through nginx and direct, it takes wget less than 1ms to retrieve the document by _id...so perhaps you have a problem outside of CouchDB?

Comment: Thanks Mark, must be a problem outside CouchDB then. I had to make sure, knew something didn't seem right.